# get method statements using javaparser

Tags: java, javaparser

Is it possible to get list of method statements without comments, i used `method.getBody()` and this is the output

```
/*
set the value of the age integer to 32
*/
int age = 32;
```

I want to make statements only are the outcome like this

```
int age = 32;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.getBody()` method return BlockStmt object which is Statements in between { and } so the following code do what i want

```
Optional<BlockStmt> block = method.getBody();
NodeList<Statement> statements = block.get().getStatements();

for (Statement tmp : statements) {
    tmp.removeComment();
    System.out.println(tmp.toString());
}
```